# Phalcon PHP Models not being loaded

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phalcon

I have Phalcon php micro application setup on my dev machine and it is working fine. However, I've pushed it to the production machine and it is saying it can't find any of the model classes. I get the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'ItemType' not found in /var/www/html/api/index.php on line 115
```

The strange thing is nothing has changed except for the password to the database which I've updated so the app can log in.

I've setup all my registered directories also

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerDirs(array(
    __DIR__ . '/models/',
    __DIR__ . '/decorators'
))->register();
```

What would be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so just found out that my dev machine is handling the file name differently. It is case sensitive on the amazon machine.

My `itemtype.php` file needed to be `ItemType.php`. This goes with all model files.

Face palm.

Comment: You will hit this error many times in development. I suggest getting acquainted with vagrant boxes in order to reduce problems when deploying to environments past development.

Comment: I always work with a case-sensitive partition on my Mac to avoid this kind of problems